# Flutter - Test - Widget not found

Tags: flutter

I have an app that allow users to log in.
I have implemented some tests but I have a problem with this one:

Test:

```
import 'package:authentication_repository/authentication_repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:login/login/views/login_form.dart';
import 'package:login/login/login_page.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

import '../helpers/helpers.dart';

class _MockAuthenticationRepository extends Mock
    implements AuthenticationRepository {}

void main() {
  group('Login Page', () {
    late AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository;
    setUpAll(() {
      authenticationRepository = _MockAuthenticationRepository();
    });

    test('is routable', () {
      expect(LoginPage.routeName, '/login');
    });

    testWidgets('renders a LoginForm', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpApp(
        RepositoryProvider.value(
          value: authenticationRepository,
          child: const LoginPage(),
        ),
      );
      expect(find.byType(LoginForm), findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}
```

The problem is the last test, the `renders a LoginForm`.

Widget:

```
import 'package:authentication_repository/authentication_repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

import '../config/config.dart';
import 'views/login_form.dart';
import 'bloc/login_bloc.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/login';

  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: appDesignSize,
      minTextAdapt: true,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Login'),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0.sp),

            /// Il BlocProvider fa in modo di caricare LoginBloc e renderlo disponibile per il child.
            child: BlocProvider(
              create: (BuildContext context) {
                return LoginBloc(
                  authenticationRepository:
                      RepositoryProvider.of<AuthenticationRepository>(context),
                );
              },
              child: const LoginForm(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure was thrown running a test:
Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: _WidgetTypeFinder:<zero widgets with type "LoginForm" (ignoring offstage widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but one was expected

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#4      main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/christiangiupponi/Dev/FlutterApps/XXXXXXXXX/test/login/login_page_test.dart:31:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)

This was caught by the test expectation on the following line:
  file:///Users/christiangiupponi/Dev/FlutterApps/XXXXXXXXX/test/login/login_page_test.dart line 31
The test description was:
  renders a LoginForm
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```